# Multi-cast on Google Cast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Does this technology support multi-cast? 
Can we send 1 stream from 1 tablet to multiple TVs?
I've googled multi-cast in connection with Google Cast as well as skimmed the API but have not been able to figure out if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, so take with a grain of sand.

[How can chrome.socket be used for broadcasting or multicasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253507/how-can-chrome-socket-be-used-for-broadcasting-or-multicasting) Looks like a good place to start.

Chromecast does adaptive bitrate streaming in Javascript using the Media Source Extensions. (Mpeg-DASH and SmoothStreaming).  I could imagine creating a Receiver that has the ability to listen to multicast traffic and play the A/V.  It will be work, however.

If you are actually going to try this, email me at Google and I'll see if there are any other hints I can provide.