# How to do UDP broadcast using chrome.sockets.udp API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, udp, broadcast

I am developing a Chrome extension and I want to broadcast a UDP packet on the local network.

I studied this Chrome [API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp#method-send).

```
 chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(s){   
        chrome.sockets.udp.bind(s.socketId, address, 0, function(ret){
            chrome.sockets.udp.send(s.socketId, data, "172.16.0.0", 5019, 
                function(sendinfo){console.log(data.byteLength); console.log(sendinfo);})})})
```

If I specified a address like `172.16.0.0`, the above code is OK. But If I changed `172.16.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`, I got `{resultCode: -10}` which indicates an error.

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "UDP",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "2",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "sockets":{
    "udp": {"send":["*:*"], "bind":["*:*"]}
  }, 
  "permissions":["system.network"]
}
```

By the way, I tried [chrome.socket](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket) which works fine even on broadcast. But the API is deprecated starting with Chrome 33.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can chrome.socket be used for broadcasting or multicasting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253507/how-can-chrome-socket-be-used-for-broadcasting-or-multicasting)

Comment: P.S. I know it's an older API, but this should apply to the newer `chrome.sockets.udp`

Comment: I tried chrome.socket. It is good. But the same method (255.255.255.255) seems not to apply to the new API.

Comment: Any news? I'm unable to send a UDP broadcast too...

Comment: Is chrome.sockets.udp allowed for extensions, or just apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Chrome 44, we have `setBroadcast` API.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp#method-setBroadcast

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it yet, but I found this:

```
"sockets": {
  "udp": {
    "bind": "*",
    "send": "*",
    "multicastMembership": ""
  }
}
```

[In this bug report](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/issues/119)

> The empty string value for `"multicastMembership"` isn't obvious at all, I had to resort to reading the C++ unit tests to find out the correct value.

Comment: It seems not work. error code: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED